# How to retain another column while using TF-IDF

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns for data. First column has text and second column in a float value

```
cleaned_text |  interaction_duration
us unveils world powerful supercomputer beat china us unveil world powerful supercomputer call summit beat previous record holder 1.0
second summit server reportedly take size two tennis court  2.3
philippinesa category fault total failurea priority p higha open time  23.0
```

I want to convert the text to TF-IDF vectors or word vectors.

Problem is using Scikit-learn's TF-IDF API, it converts it into a numpy array.

I also need to have the second column in my final dataset as another feature.

How do I make sure I can retain the final column after converting pandas dataframe to numpy

```
def tf_vectorizer(self):
        """ Extract Term frequency vector for each document
    
        """
        
        from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
        print("Extracting tfidf features from Text data...\n")
        
        self.tf_vec = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.95, min_df=2,max_features=5000,norm='l2').fit(self.data_df.cleaned_text)
    
    
        print("Tf-idf features extracted!!\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you assign your tf_vec to a new column?

If you want a vector of each row not for the entire dataset rows:

```
def textvectorizer(text):
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
    X = vectorizer.fit_transform(data_df.cleaned_text)
    print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())

data_df = data_df.assign(tf_vec = lambda x: x['cleaned_text'].apply(lambda s: textvectorizer(s))
```

Comment: How will it help in keeping the second column in same matrix? I want the text to be converted to vectors but I also need the last column to be present in same dataframe

Comment: This code keeps the last column in your dataframe but the problem is whether you want the vector of each row or the entire dataset.

Comment: each row text would be a vector.